# Limit file size of image integrating sonata media with sonata formatter ckeditor

Tags: sonata

I try to integrate sonata media with sonata formatter and all works great but I have two questios.

1. Can I limit filesize?
2. Why does it do not run validation of MIME Type?

I traced the sonata formatter code and in the CkeditorAdminController::uploadAction (https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataFormatterBundle/blob/4.x/src/Controller/CkeditorAdminController.php#L93) I see that the controller does not check if the form is valid and it is not checked if the media is valid.

On the other hand, if an error ocurrs in uploading, ckeditor just shows the error page returned by the server but th input file widget is not showen again.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed it making a controller extending the default and custom CkeditorAdminExtension

```
namespace MediaBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AdminInterface;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection;
use Sonata\FormatterBundle\Admin\CkeditorAdminExtension;

/**
 * Adds browser and upload routes to the Admin.
 *
 * @author Kévin Dunglas <kevin@les-tilleuls.coop>
 */
// we override routing definitions
class CustomCkeditorAdminExtension extends CkeditorAdminExtension
{
    public function configureRoutes(AdminInterface $admin, RouteCollection $collection)
    {
        $collection->add('ckeditor_browser', 'ckeditor_browser', [
            '_controller' => 'MediaBundle:CustomCkeditorAdmin:browser',
        ]);

        $collection->add('ckeditor_upload', 'ckeditor_upload', [
            '_controller' => 'MediaBundle:CustomCkeditorAdmin:upload',
        ]);
    }
}
```

The controller:

```
namespace MediaBundle\Controller;


use Sonata\FormatterBundle\Controller\CkeditorAdminController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class CustomCkeditorAdminController extends CkeditorAdminController
{
    CONST MAX_IMAGE_FILE_SIZE = 200 * 1024; // 200 K
    CONST VALID_IMAGE_MIME_TYPES = ['image/pjpeg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/x-png'];

    public function uploadAction()
    {
        $request = $this->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();

        if($request->isMethod('POST')){
            $file = $file = $request->files->get('upload');

            if($file instanceof UploadedFile){
                if($file->getSize() > self::MAX_IMAGE_FILE_SIZE){
                    return new Response('Too big file');
                }

                if(!in_array($file->getMimeType(), self::VALID_IMAGE_MIME_TYPES)){
                    return new Response('File is not a valid image');
                }
            }
        }

        return parent::uploadAction();
    }
}
```

And finally override the Extension parameter in parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    sonata.formatter.ckeditor.extension.class: "MediaBundle\\Admin\\CustomCkeditorAdminExtension"
```